# How to fix "Invalid remember-me token (Series/token) mismatch" Error?

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, grails-2.0, remember-me

I use Spring Security persistent logins. I persist the remember me token in my database. Sometimes I get the following error:

```
| Error 2013-07-02 13:54:14,859 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] ERROR [/buddyis].[gsp]  -  
Servlet.service() for servlet [gsp] in context with path [/buddyis] threw exception
Message: Invalid remember-me token (Series/token) mismatch. Implies previous cookie theft attack.
Line | Method
->> 1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

In my Config.groovy:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.logout.handlerNames = [
'rememberMeServices', 'securityContextLogoutHandler', 'mySecurityEventListener'
]
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.cookieName = 'RememberMe'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.alwaysRemember = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.tokenValiditySeconds = 31536000 // 365 days
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.key = 'rememberMe'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.persistent = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.persistentToken.domainClassName = 'mypackage.PersistentLogin'
```

How do I fix this error? What does it mean?

Comment: What set of configuration you have now for `rememberMe`?

Comment: I think you are a victim of this [bug](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYCORE-70) which is unresolved yet. There is a work around I guess proposed by Toby Hobson in the end.

Comment: No this is a different issue. I use persisten logins not openID.

Comment: I knew you would come back with this statement. Read each and every comment in the bug. It affects the core plugin. "I also confirm that the bug also affects the core plugin alone"- Look for this line.

Comment: I read it but it does not solve my problem.

Comment: @dmahapatro any other sugestions to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same exception in my mobile web site. 
When the http session of the user who has logged in with remember me expires and when the user access the web site again, if there are multiple parallel (ajax) requests this issue occurs.

It happens because the first of the parallel requests will refresh the remember me token and the token (which is invalidated) all the other request(s) will have mismatch the persisted token.

So you don't have many options to fix this, an option is to not have parallel requests, but in toady's mobile apps it is not much possible.

What i did is to have /me requests which is the first thing i make upon launching/loading the web app and after that i can do multiple parallel requests without worrying that i will hit this issue.